# How the average complexity is calculated

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

How the average complexity of algorithm is calculated? Worst is obvious, best also, but how the average is calculated?

Comment: here is answer in which i had calculated expected runtine :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21719141/algorithm-analysis-expected-running-time-of-recursive-function-based-on-a-rng/21728256#21728256 using expectations

Comment: Vaguely related, the expected depth of a tree selected at random from the set of all trees with N nodes is _very_ different from the expected depth of a tree generated by adding nodes to random places.  Similar concepts make calculating algorithmic "averages" and "expectations" very tricky unless you're clear _exactly_ what you're measuring.

Answer (score 2):

Average performance (time, space, etc.) complexity is found by considering all possible inputs of a given size and stating the asymptotic bound for the average of the respective measure across all those inputs.

For example, average "number of comparisons" complexity for a sort would be found by considering all N! permutations of input of size N and stating bounds on the average number of comparisons performed across all those inputs.

I.e. this is the sum of numbers of comparisons for all of the possible N! inputs divided by N!

Because the average performance across all possible inputs is equal to the expected value of the same performance measure, average performance is also called *expected performance*.

Answer (score 2):

calculate the complexity for all possible input and take and weighted sum based on their probabilities. This is also called expected runtine (similar to expectation in probabilities).

```
ET(I) = P(X=I1)*T(I1) + P(X=I2)*T(I2) + P(X=I3)*T(I3).......
```

Answer (score 0):

[Quicksort](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/363/notes/04AvgQSort.html) presents an interesting non-trivial example of calculating the average run-time performance.  As you can see the math can get quite complex, and so unfortunately I don't think there's a general equation for calculating average performance.